# evalJSON should return the array

Tags: jquery, json, parsing, eval

I have a question about jquery-json. I use version 2.4.
If you pass an array with entry to evalJSON, it returns the object inside of the array as Text. How can return with evalJSON a array?
what i do wrong?

Example:

```
var a = {'a': [1,2,45,5]}
b = jQuery.toJSON(a);
c = jQuery.evalJSON(b)
```

The value of c is now

Object
a: "[1, 2, 45, 5]"
**proto**: Object

a is not array but a String

Comment: Isn't `a.a` the array that you are looking for?

Comment: What is `jQuery.toJSON`? I can't find it on the [api](http://api.jquery.com/).

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.evalJSON(b)
```

will return an object of json type.

You can get your array using `a.a`, means you can fetch values like `a.a[0], a.a[1]` and so on

Comment: Hello Guys,
Thanks for the helpful reply. 
the problem was that the json had invalid characters.this is my solution.

$.toJSON(data).split('\\').join('').split('"[').join("[").split(']"').join("]")